# How does censoring swear words by masking the middle characters with punctuation affect the SEO of a book negatively?

Tags: seo, text

I am about to publish a book and I wanted to have the following word in the subtitle:

> f**k

Someone said that it could negatively affect SEO.

What I would like to have more information of what "negative" means, if it is advisable to change the word or if it really isn't such a big deal.

Comment: Was this someone referring to the use of the `**`, or to the use of such a (censored) word?

Comment: Believe it or not, there are ontologies for just these situations. Your censored term will be indexed for the uncensored term. The claim that it is bad for SEO is just plain silliness. Do not worry about it. You are fine! Cheers!!

Comment: thank you closetnoc - does that mean it will be adjusted or do I need to do that?

Comment: In the visible text, it is not necessary to have the word uncensored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to SEO, "negative" means a lower page ranking. That being said, in your case you have nothing to worry about.

Google will probably categorize this specific word as gibberish. Even then, according to [this patent](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=8,554,769.PN.&OS=PN/8,554,769&RS=PN/8,554,769) it will determine the gibberish threshold of your page as a whole. If you only use this censored word once or twice, you will not reach the gibberish threshold and the page as a whole will not be categorized as gibberish. Context matters a lot. Α censored word thrown in a generally structured and understandable context will not matter so much compared to a page filled with incomprehensible text. So as you said, no big deal, actually I would go as far to say no deal at all.